# How to calculate where to crop an image - imagecopyresampled

Tags: php, image, image-processing

Now my code gives me an image with correct scaled down height and width, but uses the top of the original image. I would like it to use the center of the image. But I can't figure out how to calculate the value of dst_y for imagecopyresampled to do this. Can anyone please help me to solve :-)

```
<?php

function ReSize ($source,$destination,$dest_imagex,$dest_imagey,$quality) {

$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
// Get dimensions of the original image
$source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
$source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);

$after_width = $dest_imagex;

    //get the reduced width
    $reduced_width = ($source_imagex - $after_width);
    //now convert the reduced width to a percentage and round it to 2 decimal places
    $reduced_radio = round(($reduced_width / $source_imagex) * 100, 2);

    //ALL GOOD! let's reduce the same percentage from the height and round it to 2 decimal places.
    $reduced_height = round(($source_imagey / 100) * $reduced_radio, 2);
    //reduce the calculated height from the original height
    $after_height = $source_imagey - $reduced_height;

      $dst_y = 0; // The calculation I cannot figure out.....

$dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);
imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, $dst_y, 0, 0, $after_width, $after_height, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);

$cache_folder = 'images/cache/';
$new_image = $cache_folder . rawurlencode($destination). '_' . $dest_imagex . 'x' . $dest_imagey . '.jpg';
imagejpeg($dest_image, $new_image,$quality);

echo $new_image;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want a CSS "cover" type resizing, which you have two options:

- Vertically fit image
- Horizontally fit image

find the source and destination ratio first:

```
$dest_ratio = $dest_imagex / $dest_imagey;
$source_ratio = $source_imagex / $source_imagey;
```

If the source ratio is bigger than the destionation ratio, it means you need a horizontal fit scale, otherwise you need a vertical fit scale.

---

### Horizontal Fit Scale

[image]

```
imagecopyresampled(
    $dest_image,
    $source_image,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    ($source_imagey - ($source_imagex * $dest_ratio)) / 2,
    $dest_imagex,
    $dest_imagex * $source_ratio,
    $source_imagex,
    $source_imagey
);
```

---

### Vertical Fit scale

[image: Vertical Fit Scale]

```
imagecopyresampled(
    $dest_image,
    $source_image,
    0,
    0,
    ($source_imagex - ($source_imagey / $dest_ratio)) / 2,
    0,
    $dest_imagey / $source_ratio,
    $dest_imagey,
    $source_imagex,
    $source_imagey
);
```

---

### All together:

```
function crop($source, $dest, $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $quality)
{
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    // Get dimensions of the original image
    $source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
    $source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);
    $source_ratio = $source_imagey / $source_imagex;
    $dest_ratio = $dest_imagey / $dest_imagex;

    $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);
    imagefill($dest_image, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($dest_image, 255, 0, 0));

    if ($dest_ratio >= $source_ratio) {
        imagecopyresampled(
            $dest_image,
            $source_image,
            0,
            0,
            ($source_imagex - ($source_imagey / $dest_ratio)) / 2,
            0,
            $dest_imagey / $source_ratio,
            $dest_imagey,
            $source_imagex,
            $source_imagey
        );
    } else {
        imagecopyresampled(
            $dest_image,
            $source_image,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            ($source_imagey - ($source_imagex * $dest_ratio)) / 2,
            $dest_imagex,
            $dest_imagex * $source_ratio,
            $source_imagex,
            $source_imagey
        );
    }
    imagejpeg($dest_image, $dest, $quality);
}
```

### Usage

```
crop("image1.jpg", "image1_resized.jpg", 100, 100, 100);
```

Comment: Did you test it directly or adapted to your code? I tested it locally too and it seemed to work.. Strange. I'll test with non squared dimensions again.

Comment: Directly with your code. Only added echo $dest; at the bottom to get the output of the new filename.

Comment: Works perfect! :-) Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: I would like to correct your answer a little. It is not css "cover" behavior it is actually "contain" behavior. What "cover" does is stretch to fill. CSS "contain" does stretch to fit.

Comment: Cover allows the image to overflow the container whereas contain doesn't. Cover and contain stretches proportionally to fill the container.

Comment: everyone needs to upvote this answer!